# Detect if a method was overridden using Reflection (C#)

Tags: c#, reflection, overriding

Say I have a base class TestBase where I define a virtual method TestMe()

```
class TestBase
{
    public virtual bool TestMe() {  }
}
```

Now I inherit this class:

```
class Test1 : TestBase
{
    public override bool TestMe() {}
}
```

Now, using Reflection, I need to find if the method TestMe has been overriden in child class - is it possible?

What I need it for - I am writing a designer visualizer for type "object" to show the whole hierarchy of inheritance and also show which virtual methods were overridden at which level.

Comment: I don't know exactly how, but something like this must be possible.  There's an excellent tool called "RedGate Reflector" that will show the logic of a method in a library.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Given the type `Test1`, you can determine whether it has its own <strike>implementation</strike> declaration of `TestMe`:

```
typeof(Test1).GetMethod("TestMe").DeclaringType == typeof(Test1)
```

If the declaration came from a base type, this will evaluate false.

Note that since this is testing declaration, not true implementation, this *will* return true if `Test1` is also abstract and `TestMe` is abstract, since `Test1` would have its own declaration. If you want to exclude that case, add `&& !GetMethod("TestMe").IsAbstract`

Comment: This solution is not complete. It does not cover the case in which Test1 declares a method with the same name but different parameters. If the test above evaluates to true you only know that Test1 has a method with TestMe name but you do not know if it is an override. You need to also use the GetBaseDefinition() method. If this call returns a MethodInfo object that has the DeclaringType == typeof(TestBase), only then you can know for sure you have an override.

Comment: @Ciprian this isn't a complete code solution, just explaining where to find the relevant parts of reflection to pull if off.

Comment: Yes I did, it's incorrect/very limited, and going from your code to a working solution is quite a bit of work. You did not even mention essential APIs like `GetBaseDefinition()`, and issues related to method hiding or differing method signatures.

Comment: If you want to check in a abstract base class if a derived class overrides a method you can do this check with this.GetType like:

this.GetType().GetMethod("MethodName").DeclaringType == this.GetType()

Answer (score 39):

I was unable to get [Ken Beckett's proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020948/150) to work.  Here's what I settled on:

```
    public static bool IsOverride(MethodInfo m) {
        return m.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType != m.DeclaringType;
    }
```

There are tests in [the gist](https://gist.github.com/EdVinyard/5571449).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!
Just a remark about getting the MethodInfo instance. I first made the mistake to get it through:
`typeof(SomeType).GetMethod(someFunctionName)`
With this MethodInfo instance IsOverride doesn't work. You need to do this instead:
`someTypeInstance.GetType().GetMethod(someFunctionName)`
This is perfectly logical of course, but still somewhat subtle. Apparently, when calling GetType(), a reference to the instance is kept in the Type object that is returned.

Comment: @DimitriC.I am using Assembly.Load([myAssembleyNameHere]).GetTypes() and it's working perfectly fine.. should be marked as accepted solution.

Comment: @DimitriC. No, in the technique shown here, no reference to the instance is in any way "kept in the `Type` object that's returned;" in fact it's exactly the other way around: every runtime *instance* knows its actual `Type`, which you can obtain via `GetType()` (To be precise, the `Type` of a type instance at runtime is `RuntimeType`, a type derived from `Type`). The good news is, despite the minor snafu in your explanation, the code you provided is technically the only way to get truly 100% correct behavior, so it's one of the most important gems on this page...

Comment: ...Because most of the examples on this page consider static typing only, e.g. `typeof(SomeType)`, they will therefore fail for any/all instance of a `SomeType`-derived class that indeed overrides the method, even though `SomeType` might not. Since any `SomeType`-derived instance is presumably entitled to show up, you need to independently check each runtime instance via `GetType()` on every call. Not doing so is probably what caused the problem you mentioned seeing initially.

Comment: Works like a charm. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 28):

As @CiprianBortos pointed out, the accepted answer is not complete and will lead to a nasty bug in your code if you use it as-is.

His comment provides the magic solution `GetBaseDefinition()`, but there's no need to check the `DeclaringType` if you want a general-purpose `IsOverride` check (which I think was the point of this question), just `methodInfo.GetBaseDefinition() != methodInfo`.

Or, provided as an extension method on `MethodInfo`, I think this will do the trick:

```
public static class MethodInfoUtil
{
    public static bool IsOverride(this MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return (methodInfo.GetBaseDefinition() != methodInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation returns true for inherited methods -- see [NUnit test gist](https://gist.github.com/EdVinyard/5571213).  `m.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType != m.DeclaringType` works better.

Comment: code has a syntax error, what is "this" keyword representing?

Comment: MethodInfo could be different if ReflectedType is different.

Comment: @AZ_ `this` is part of the signature that makes the `IsOverride` method a static method.

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution which will also work for protected member and properties is as follows:

```
var isDerived = typeof(Test1 ).GetMember("TestMe", 
               BindingFlags.NonPublic 
             | BindingFlags.Instance 
             | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Length == 0;
```

This is a repost of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233905/how-to-detect-if-virtual-method-is-overridden-in-c/7234217#7234217), which in turn had made references to this question.

Answer (score 2):

A method that also works in some non trivial cases:

```
public bool Overrides(MethodInfo baseMethod, Type type)
{
    if(baseMethod==null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("baseMethod");
    if(type==null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
    if(!type.IsSubclassOf(baseMethod.ReflectedType))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type must be subtype of {0}",baseMethod.DeclaringType));
    while(type!=baseMethod.ReflectedType)
    {
        var methods=type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance|
                                    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly|
                                    BindingFlags.Public|
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if(methods.Any(m=>m.GetBaseDefinition()==baseMethod))
            return true;
        type=type.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And a few ugly tests:

```
public bool OverridesObjectEquals(Type type)
{
    var baseMethod=typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[]{typeof(object)});
    return Overrides(baseMethod,type);
}

void Main()
{
    (OverridesObjectEquals(typeof(List<int>))==false).Dump();
    (OverridesObjectEquals(typeof(string))==true).Dump();
    (OverridesObjectEquals(typeof(Hider))==false).Dump();
    (OverridesObjectEquals(typeof(HiderOverrider))==false).Dump();
    (OverridesObjectEquals(typeof(Overrider))==true).Dump();
    (OverridesObjectEquals(typeof(OverriderHider))==true).Dump();
    (OverridesObjectEquals(typeof(OverriderNothing))==true).Dump();
}

class Hider
{
  public virtual new bool Equals(object o)
    {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}


class HiderOverrider:Hider
{
  public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

class Overrider
{
  public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}


class OverriderHider:Overrider
{
  public new bool Equals(object o)
    {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

class OverriderNothing:Overrider
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288928/993388) there could also be a simple way to check if a virtual method was overridden without to know the exact derived or base type using a test for the `MethodAttributes.NewSlot` attribute:

```
public static bool HasOverride(this MethodInfo method)
{
    return (method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.Virtual) != 0 &&
           (method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.NewSlot) == 0;
}
```

Together with another extension method

```
private const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

public static bool HasOverride(this Type type, string name, params Type[] argTypes)
{
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(name, Flags, null, CallingConventions.HasThis,
        argTypes, new ParameterModifier[0]);
    return method != null && method.HasOverride();
}
```

you could then simply call

```
bool hasOverride = GetType().HasOverride(nameof(MyMethod), typeof(Param1Type),
    typeof(Param2Type), ...);
```

to check if `MyMethod` is overridden in a derived class.

As far as I've tested this, it seemed to work fine (on my machine™).

Comment: Beware here, I think you misunderstand the meaning of the `NewSlot` flag. It is ***not*** asserted for "normal" virtual/abstract methods which, by default, participate in the traditional virtual overriding mechanism. Rather, `NewSlot` refers to the (idiosyncratic?) .NET capability of selectively *cancelling* the polymorphism chain. The concept corresponding to `NewSlot` in **C#** is the `new` keyword, which can be applied to an (otherwise-)virtual method in a derived class in order to detach it, plus all its further derivations, from base method polymorphism.

Comment: @GlennSlayden Thank you for pointing this out. As I understood the explanations in the referenced answer, the `NewSlot` flag is set (along with the `Virtual` flag) for both base virtual methods and methods hiding an implementation in a base class, because in both of these cases the methods will get a new slot in the vtable of the class. On the other hand an override method will not get a new slot in the vtable and thus have only the `Virtual` flag set. Anyway, as you've already said, the answer from ESV is actually the best and most straight-forward solution to the question here.

Comment: I stand corrected if the `NewSlot` flag is asserted on the base method as well, thanks for that. And I guess the OPs problem statement is underspecified about whether a `NewSlot` (`new` keyword in C#) derived method is supposed to be analyzed as "HasOverride" or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better, safer and faster way to do it.
This technique makes sense if your class instance is going to have a long life and the IsOverridden check must be performed several times.

To solve this problem we can use a cache and C# delegates, much faster than reflection!

```
// Author: Salvatore Previti - 2011.

/// <summary>We need a delegate type to our method to make this technique works.</summary>
delegate int MyMethodDelegate(string parameter);

/// <summary>An enum used to mark cache status for IsOverridden.</summary>
enum OverriddenCacheStatus
{
    Unknown,
    NotOverridden,
    Overridden
}

public class MyClassBase
{
    /// <summary>Cache for IsMyMethodOverridden.</summary>
    private volatile OverriddenCacheStatus pMyMethodOverridden;

    public MyClassBase()
    {
        // Look mom, no overhead in the constructor!
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if method MyMethod is overridden; False if not.
    /// We have an overhead the first time this function is called, but the
    /// overhead is a lot less than using reflection alone. After the first time
    /// this function is called, the operation is really fast! Yeah!
    /// This technique works better if IsMyMethodOverridden() should
    /// be called several times on the same object.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsMyMethodOverridden()
    {
        OverriddenCacheStatus v = this.pMyMethodOverridden;
        switch (v)
        {
            case OverriddenCacheStatus.NotOverridden:
                return false; // Value is cached! Faaast!

            case OverriddenCacheStatus.Overridden:
                return true; // Value is cached! Faaast!
        }

        // We must rebuild cache.
        // We use a delegate: also if this operation allocates a temporary object
        // it is a lot faster than using reflection!

        // Due to "limitations" in C# compiler, we need the type of the delegate!
        MyMethodDelegate md = this.MyMethod;

        if (md.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(MyClassBase))
        {
            this.pMyMethodOverridden = OverriddenCacheStatus.NotOverridden;
            return false;
        }

        this.pMyMethodOverridden = OverriddenCacheStatus.Overridden;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>Our overridable method. Can be any kind of visibility.</summary>
    protected virtual int MyMethod(string parameter)
    {
        // Default implementation
        return 1980;
    }

    /// <summary>Demo function that calls our method and print some stuff.</summary>
    public void DemoMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + " result:" + this.MyMethod("x") + " overridden:" + this.IsMyMethodOverridden());
    }
}

public class ClassSecond :
    MyClassBase
{
}

public class COverridden :
    MyClassBase
{
    protected override int MyMethod(string parameter)
    {
        return 2011;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClassBase a = new MyClassBase();
        a.DemoMethod();

        a = new ClassSecond();
        a.DemoMethod();

        a = new COverridden();
        a.DemoMethod();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When you run this program as a console application, it will print:

```
MyClassBase result:1980 overridden:False
ClassSecond result:1980 overridden:False
COverridden result:2011 overridden:True
```

Tested with Visual Studio 2010, C# 4.0.
Should work also on previous versions, but it can be a little slower on C# less than 3.0 due to optimizations to delegates in the new releases, tests about this would be appreciated :)
However it will be still faster than using reflection!

Comment: Your caching strategy is quite suboptimal. I'd rather use a static dictionary, so you can get a general helper method. `ConditionalWeakTable<Type,Dictionary<MethodInfo,bool>>` seems like a good choice. And of course it's broken in the same way as Rex's answer.

Comment: Well from my point of view, is not suboptimal if you have a small number of instances and if the object have a very long life. Is subotpimal if the instance have a short life, as I said in the answer. Second, it works if you add a method with other parameters, since we are using a delegate to do the trick. Using a dictionary is not thread safe, you would need a concurrent dictionary, at least, and of course, looking in a concurrent or locked dictionary is slower than looking into a field. It all depends on the requirements actually.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static bool HasOverridingMethod(this Type type, MethodInfo baseMethod) {
        return type.GetOverridingMethod( baseMethod ) != null;
    }
    public static MethodInfo GetOverridingMethod(this Type type, MethodInfo baseMethod) {
        var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod;
        return type.GetMethods( flags ).FirstOrDefault( i => baseMethod.IsBaseMethodOf( i ) );
    }
    private static bool IsBaseMethodOf(this MethodInfo baseMethod, MethodInfo method) {
        return baseMethod.DeclaringType != method.DeclaringType && baseMethod == method.GetBaseDefinition();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple 1-liner based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16530993/6841224) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815481/6841224) answers:

```cs
typeof(T).GetMember(nameof("Method")).OfType<MethodInfo>()
                .Where(m => m.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType != m.DeclaringType);
```