# Test if a method is an override?

Tags: c#, reflection, oop, system.reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if a method was overridden using Reflection (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932421/detect-if-a-method-was-overridden-using-reflection-c)

Is there a way to tell if a method is an override? For e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual void DoSomething() {}
    public virtual int GimmeIntPleez() { return 0; }
}

public class BabyFoo: Foo
{
    public override int GimmeIntPleez() { return -1; }
}
```

Is it possible to reflect on `BabyFoo` and tell if `GimmeIntPleez` is an override?

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932421/detect-if-a-method-was-overridden-using-reflection-c

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks, Petar. How do you find such threads?

Comment: @Rowland: At execution (aka run-time) time. At compile time, I could use a regex on the source file, if that was what you were alluding to.

Comment: Using the search function on StackOverflow(upper-right corner) - "C# method override" is just enough to find the threads. Also you can use google:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MethodInfo.DeclaringType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx) to determine if the method is an override (assuming that it's also `IsVirtual = true`).

From the documentation:

> *...note that when B overrides virtual
>   method M from A, it essentially
>   redefines (or redeclares) this method.
>   Therefore, B.M's MethodInfo reports
>   the declaring type as B rather than A,
>   even though A is where this method was
>   originally declared...*

Here's an example:

```
var someType = typeof(BabyFoo);
var mi = someType.GetMethod("GimmeIntPleez");
// assuming we know GimmeIntPleez is in a base class, it must be overriden
if( mi.IsVirtual && mi.DeclaringType == typeof(BabyFoo) )
    { ... }
```

Comment: My comment comes a bit late, but here it is. I don't think this solution will do because the BabyFoo type may declare its own virtual method with the same name but different parameters. This solution will not detect that.

Answer (score 14):

Test against `MethodInfo.GetBaseDefinition()`. If the function is an override, it will return a different method in a base class. If it's not, the same method object will be returned.

> When overridden in a derived class, returns the MethodInfo object for the method on the direct or indirect base class in which the method represented by this instance was first declared.

Comment: +1 because you are the first one mentioning the GetBaseDefinition method, which I think is the correct way to figure out whether a method is an override.