# Determine whether a C# method has keyword 'override' using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, overriding, keyword

I had expected to find an answer easily to this problem, but I didn't.
I'd like to know if it is possible to determine whether a method has the keyword 'override' attributed to it, given its instance of `MethodInfo`.

I was thinking maybe the following would achieve that:

```
/// <summary> Returns whether the specified methodInfo is attributed with the keyword 'override'. </summary>
public static bool IsOverriding(this MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    if (methodInfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    return methodInfo.DeclaringType != methodInfo.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType;
}
```

I've sucessfully tested some non-virtual, virtual and abstract examples, but I feel like I'm missing some scenarios, maybe with hiding or generics(although I can't figure out how that would come into play).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932421/detect-if-a-method-was-overridden-using-reflection-c

Comment: @James, Hm... that is indeed a similar question, though not exactly the same. I searched using the word 'override', and unforunately that post wasn't found, probably because it uses the word 'overridden'. The answer there however, doesn't suit me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't see how *that would come into play* either. Your code there does indeed determine whether a method is defined or overriden.

In the case of hiding, the declaring type is the one that hides the method via `new`.
In the case of generics, all methods are defined by the template class.

Answer (score 3):

I try to find this thing also. From the question, you give the idea to get `IsOverriding` work for `override` keyword. However for hiding I try to create `IsHiding` for keyword `new`. Here is the basic C# OOP:

- `override` only used when the based method contain `abstract` or `virtual` modifier.
- `new` is used to hide based method with the same name but...
- `new` cannot be apply to `abstract` base method because it generate compiler error.
- However the interesting part is `new` also can be applied to method if the base method contain `virtual`.

The inseresting part is we can hide or override `virtual` method. We know that `GetBaseDefinition()` will return the base `MethodInfo` if we `override` a `virtual` method. but the key to differentiate it is the `GetBaseDefinition()` will return the same `MethodInfo` instead of it base `MethodInfo` if we hiding `virtual` method.

`override` keyword is a must while `new` is only used to suppress the warning message. So we can diffrentiate `override` and `new` by the `IsAbstract` and `IsVirtual` combine with `DeclaringType` and `BaseType`.

```
    public static bool IsOverriding(this MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (methodInfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("methodInfo");
        return methodInfo.DeclaringType != methodInfo.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType;
    }

    public static bool IsHiding(this MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (methodInfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("methodInfo");
        if (methodInfo.DeclaringType == methodInfo.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType)
        {
            var baseType = methodInfo.DeclaringType.BaseType;
            if (baseType != null)
            {
                MethodInfo hiddenBaseMethodInfo = null;
                var methods = baseType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
                foreach (var mi in methods)
                    if (mi.Name == methodInfo.Name)
                    {
                        var miParams = mi.GetParameters();
                        var methodInfoParams = methodInfo.GetParameters();
                        if (miParams.Length == methodInfoParams.Length)
                        {
                            var i = 0;
                            for (; i < miParams.Length; i++)
                            {
                                if (miParams[i].ParameterType != methodInfoParams[i].ParameterType
                                    || ((miParams[i].Attributes ^ methodInfoParams[i].Attributes).HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.Out))) break;

                                // Simplified from:
                                //if (miParams[i].ParameterType != methodInfoParams[i].ParameterType
                                //    || (miParams[i].Attributes.HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.Out) && !methodInfoParams[i].Attributes.HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.Out))
                                //    || !(miParams[i].Attributes.HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.Out) && methodInfoParams[i].Attributes.HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.Out))) break;
                            }
                            if (i == miParams.Length)
                            {
                                hiddenBaseMethodInfo = mi;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                if (hiddenBaseMethodInfo != null && !hiddenBaseMethodInfo.IsPrivate) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I test it using the simple inheritance and it works. I don't think about generic method..yet..

---

**EDIT**: I just change the code above because I forgot the idea about inherited type can contain newly declared method which is should not threated as new. `IsHiding()` will first make sure it have the same `DeclaringType` (it seems like new) but need to look at the base declaring types by `DeclaringType.BaseType` if a method with the same name exist.

Note that because of there is no `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`, `GetMethod()` will search through the entire base types, so no need to recursively search to each base types. `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` is used to include static method in abstract-abstract base class like this:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public static void Stat() { }
}
public abstract class B : A
{
}
public class C: B
{
    public new static void Stat() { }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: I just fix the `IsHiding()` above to check for base method **overloads** and prevent `AmbiguousMatchException` by using `GetMethods()` instead of `GetMethod()`. The overloads tested to work with combination with different parameters, mix with `ref`, `out`, `params` and optional parameter. Signature for overloads being compared based on parameter count, parameter types and its modifier:

- `ref` or `out` included in the signature but both cannot be overloaded to each other.
- return type, optional (default value) and `params` on right most parameter should be ignored

`ref` compared by the `ParameterType` itself (see the ending '&' during debugging) and no need to compare by the `IsByRef` while the `out` compared by the `Attributes` flag. I am using simplified expression bitwise XOR to skip the loop if and only if one of the attributes has flag `Out` which makes the signature different. Don't confused with `HasFlag` in .NET 4, it just want to make sure `Out` bit is 1 by the XOR result.

Comment: You may have done al this work for nothing.... The class `MethodBase` has the property `IsHideBySig`, which pretty much does exactly what your `IsHiding` method does :P sry :P

Comment: Really? I just ignore it because the name confusing. should be something like `IsHideBySignature`. Forget about `IsHiding` because it will throw `AmbiguousMatchException` if the method name have overloads. I will use `IsHideBySig`.

Comment: `IsHideBySig` seems not work exactly I think of. it will simply return `true` all the time. Seems does not represent as `new` keyword. MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.ishidebysig.aspx claim it will return true on a member declared with the C# `new` modifier but it also return `true` for all other cases like `override`, newly declared method and extern!

Comment: You're right. Apparently it doesn't do what I thought it does either :P In that case your IsHiding method may prove useful sometimes(and I should edit my code to some fix bugs related to this misunderstanding of mine XD)

Comment: Now `IsHiding` should be perfect and support for method overloading in base type. So now I can generate `new` keyword based on this extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public static bool IsOverriding(this MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    if (methodInfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    return methodInfo.GetBaseDefinition() != methodInfo;
}
```

Comment: -1. That doesn't work. Consider the case abstract class A { public abstract void Foo(); } abstract class B : A { } and then typeof(B).GetMethod("Foo").IsOverriding() would return true, which it shouldn't.