# Get collection of methods with the same name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've got some code (for helping with url routing) that tries to find an action method in a controller.

My controller looks like so:

```
public ActionResult Item(int id)
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Item(MyViewModel model)
{
    //do other stuff here
    return View(model);
}
```

The following code attempts to find a method matching the url action:

```
//cont is a System.Type object representing the controller
MethodInfo actionMethod = cont.GetMethod(action);
```

Today this code threw a `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found` which makes sense given my two methods have the same name.

I took a look at the available methods of the `Type` object and found `public MethodInfo[] GetMethods();` which seems to do what I want, except there doesn't seem to be an overload for searching for a method with a specific name.

I could just use this method and search everything it returns, but I'm wondering if there's another (simpler) way to obtain a list of all methods in a class with a specific name, when there are multiple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with searching through the result of `GetMethods` really, but if you really wanted to, you could do:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;

var myOverloads = typeof(MyClass)
                  .GetMember("OverloadedMethodName", MemberTypes.Method, flags)
                  .Cast<MethodInfo>();
```

...which uses [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dk6tw7k.aspx). You may need to change the binding-flags as per your requirements.

I checked reference-source and found that this internally relies on a cached-multimap keyed by member-name (see RuntimeType.GetMemberList), so it *should* be somewhat more efficient than searching in client code each time.

You could also do (more convenient but slightly less efficient, in theory at least):

```
var myOverloads = typeof(MyClass).GetMember("OverloadedMethodName")
                                 .OfType<MethodInfo>();
```

Comment: Trying it now. I am concerned about the efficiency since this code runs for every single request.

Comment: If you are so concerned, why not memoize yourself? That's likely to be much more efficient since Reflection has to create a new array for you every time (it can't cache the array itself since you might mutate it and it doesn't trust you not to).

Comment: It seems that the number of members of the type doesn't influence the speed of `GetMember` (or the impact is neglectable compared to `GetMethods`)!?!

Comment: I hadn't gotten that far, though I may well end up doing that.

Comment: By the way, are you looking to execute the method? If so (and you are really concerned by performance, backed by profiling), I suggest memoizing yourself *and* using Delegate.CreateDelegate.

Comment: No, I don't need to actually execute it (not in my code anyway). All I do is modify the parameters of the route if the action is found.

Answer (score 2):

Just Get the Collection of Methods with `GetMethods()` amd filter them by using a Lambda Expression: `GetMethods().Where(p => p.Name == "XYZ").ToList();`

Comment: I did specifically mention I was hoping to **not** have to do this, but thanks nonetheless :)

Comment: We had that topic yesterday. It turns out that, if you want to search only by Name, there is no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cont.GetMethod(action, new [] {typeof(MyViewModel )})
```