# about isOverrided at C#

Tags: c#, reflection, overriding, derived-class

What should I do to distinguish it whether a derived class implements overriding of a method?

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void targetMethod() { return; }
}

class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public bool isOverrideTargetMethod()
    {
        //Here, I wants to judge whether DerivedClass is overrided targetMethod.
     }
     public override void targetMethod()
     {
         base.targetMethod();
     }
}
```

Comment: add a isOverrideTargetMethod boolean property in derived class and assign true in override method in derived class

Comment: I do not want to add a special property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all what you are trying to do is not very good in design perspective but if you really want to do Reflection is the answer.

```
using System.Reflection;

Type classType = typeof(DerivedClass);
MethodInfo method = classType.GetMethod("targetMethod");
if (method.DeclaringType == typeof(BaseClass))
    Console.WriteLine("targetMethod not overridden.");
else
Console.WriteLine("targetMethod is overridden " + method.DeclaringType.Name);
```

Comment: Because I want to judge overriding by great many methods, the reflection is convenient.Thank you.

Comment: The reflection is slow to judge it for run time.
For example, please give me the following ideas
・ How to judge statically in a compile time
・ How to cache of reflection

Comment: Try to de somthing like this, The typeof keyword takes a compile-time type identifier                                                                                                        var isDerived = typeof(DerivedClass).GetMember("targetMethod", 
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                 | BindingFlags.Instance 
                 | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Length == 0;

Comment: Is there the way not to use Literal "targetMethod"?

Comment: Plese refer to solution given by "Salvatore Previti" at link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932421/detect-if-a-method-was-overridden-using-reflection-c)

Comment: It was solved by a linked article. Thank you. ((Action)targetMethod).Method.DeclaringType == typeof(BaseClass)