# public override void X(){ base.X(); } How can this code change program function?

Tags: c#

Why can Overriding a a virtual method, but only calling the base method and doing nothing else, cause a change in how a program functions?

For Example:

```
    public override void OnDeserialize(NetworkReader reader, bool initialState)
    {
        base.OnDeserialize(reader, initialState);
    }
```

Overriding:

```
    public virtual void OnDeserialize ( NetworkReader reader, bool initialState );
```

Causes different outcomes.

In my case a networking Library called UNET does not work.

You can see the minimised test case [here](https://github.com/jethrogillgren/UNET_DeserializeTestCase), which includes the logs.

Comment: Can you describe how it causes different outcomes? Can you provide an [MCVE]?

Comment: What different outcome it causes?

Comment: Just building the test case, as I believe it to surely be a bug?   Having the method available causes Unity UNET networking to fail.  I intended to submit it to Unity, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something about C# and override

Comment: Sorry if it's a bad question, I was hoping it was clear and was hoping that the simple answer is "No"?  Will update with the test case one i finish minimizing

Comment: Yes... The simple answer is `No`. It doesn't change anything if you are just calling base method from the overridden method. I asked for clarification to understand if you have any  different expectations from the code.

Comment: @john Sure, I updated the Q, please see the test case - sorry for delay was minimising it.
 You can see the logs in the repo too.
I have a bug in with Unity which can be found here https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?1012108_nj3qm5pqjd3av052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function change should not happen if overrides are used as intended, however function changes are still easily possible.

Libraries could use Reflection to [determine if a class is overriding a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932421/detect-if-a-method-was-overridden-using-reflection-c), and change it's actions dependent on that check.

In this case it seems to be a bug with Unity.  I think it checks to see if a method needs to be called, as an optimisation, are incorrectly written, and cause the change in program flow.