# How do i know if a method wasn't derived from base classes C#

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Given this piece of code, how do i know using "i" variable that the method wasn't derived from base classes, but it was declared in the most downcasted class?
For example, i don't need no GetType(), ToString() etc and so forth methods to be printed about.

```
MethodInfo[] methods = Type.GetType(
            "Probabilities_Theory.ProbabilitiesTheory").GetMethods();

foreach (var i in methods)
{
    if (!i.IsVirtual) // another condition needed
        Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I don't need to know if it was overriden or not, because for example GetType() method is not virtual for the reason. But i still don't want GetType() to be printed about.

What's common in GetType() and the other methods that are virtual is that they all weren't declared in the most downcasted class.

I  could do it this way:

```
if (i.DeclaringType == typeof(ProbabilitiesTheory))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

But i want my code to be more automatic, more programmic and stuff. Like one doesn't know what type it is.

Comment: That sounsd like it could be a XY Problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem But for me, any use of Reflection does. Usually you just figure that out by downcasting the type. Then you do know.

Comment: Check the properties of `MethodInfo`. There should be one telling which type declared that method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if a method was overridden using Reflection (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932421/detect-if-a-method-was-overridden-using-reflection-c)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = Type.GetType("Probabilities_Theory.ProbabilitiesTheory")
                           .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Comment: Somewhy it didn't work out. I've gotten an array of 0 elements from executing that

Comment: If you give bindingFlags, you must give all relevant, so `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)`

Comment: @KlausGütter You're right, I've missed that point, thanks for the correction. :)