# How to find the base-class property of a covariant property override in C# 9 using Reflection

Tags: c#

Given the following example

```cs
class BaseProperty
{
    
}

class DerivedProperty : BaseProperty
{
    
}

abstract class BaseWithAbstractProperty
{
    public abstract BaseProperty Property { get;  }
    public virtual BaseProperty OtherProperty { get; }
}

sealed class DerivedWithCovariantOverride : BaseWithAbstractProperty
{
    public override DerivedProperty Property { get;  }
    
    public override BaseProperty OtherProperty { get;  }
}
```

How do I determine that property `Property` of class `DerivedWithCovariantOverride` is an override of the `abstract` property with the same name on class `BaseWithAbstractProperty`? With `OtherProperty`, the following will return `true`

```
var otherProperty = typeof(BaseWithAbstractProperty).GetProperty("OtherProperty", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
var derivedProperty = typeof(DerivedWithCovariantOverride).GetProperty("OtherProperty", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

Console.WriteLine(derivedProperty.GetMethod.GetBaseDefinition() == otherProperty.GetMethod);
```

But with the covariant override, the following will return `false`

```
var baseProperty = typeof(BaseWithAbstractProperty).GetProperty("Property", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
var covariantProperty = typeof(DerivedWithCovariantOverride).GetProperty("Property", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

Console.WriteLine(covariantProperty.GetMethod.GetBaseDefinition() == baseProperty.GetMethod);
```

The only special thing I see is that the `GetMethod` on the covariant property returns a `MethodInfo` which has attribute `PreserveBaseOverridesAttribute`. Looking at the docs and the dotnet Github repo, it's clearly related to this covariant behavior. But all in all, it almost looks like that property is not a normal override.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932421/detect-if-a-method-was-overridden-using-reflection-c

Comment: No, because neither `GetBaseDefinition` or `DeclaredType` point back at the base. This works with normal virtual overrides, but not with covariant properties.

Comment: `typeof(DerivedWithCovariantOverride).GetProperties()` returns 2 different properties named Property with differences in DeclaringType, PropertyType, BindingFlags etc. I'm not sure what the easiest, most correct values are to key off of are.