# .NET: Using reflection how can I tell if a property is shadowing another property?

Tags: .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does reflection tell me when a property is hiding an inherited member with the 'new' keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288357/how-does-reflection-tell-me-when-a-property-is-hiding-an-inherited-member-with-th)

Using reflection how can I tell if a property is shadowing another property? I am working on some code generation and I need that information to call said properties correctly.

Exmaple:

```
class A{
    int Foo {get;set;}
}

class B:A{
    string new Foo {get;set;}
}
```

Code I would need to generate:

```
someB.Foo = "";
((A)someB).Foo = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There weren't any answers marked as correct in the duplicate so I copied the one that seems to work after minor corrections.

```
    public static bool IsHidingMember(PropertyInfo self)
    {
        Type baseType = self.DeclaringType.BaseType;
        if (baseType == null)
            return false;

        PropertyInfo baseProperty = baseType.GetProperty(self.Name);

        if (baseProperty == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (baseProperty.DeclaringType == self.DeclaringType)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var baseMethodDefinition = baseProperty.GetGetMethod().GetBaseDefinition();
        var thisMethodDefinition = self.GetGetMethod().GetBaseDefinition();

        return baseMethodDefinition.DeclaringType != thisMethodDefinition.DeclaringType;
    }
```